# Magento Checkout Current Session Shipping Address

Tags: magento

I have added a new step in my checkout process, and I am attempting to return the current address in a this new part of the Checkout process.  This is currently only returning the default shipping address it would seem, as any changes made in the checkout process are not picked up.

I am attempting to retrieve the name stored in the current session shipping address with the code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getName();
```

However this fails to retrieve the shipping address name that I have modified in the Shipping Information step.

When checking if this is a problem in my (new) step only, I saw that when I add the above code to the template file: `/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`, I see the desired session name for the checkout session, when I go to the Shipping Method step of the process.

However if I then add the same line of code to the Shipping Method parent template file: `/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml`, then the name shown will not be the current session address, and it appears to output the name associated with the default shipping address for the customer.

I am testing with CE 1.7.0.2.

Any help is appreciated in assisting me to understand the cause of this behaviour.